# Защита данных программы

Tags: c#, защита

Необходимо защитить данные которые используются и генерируются программой в процессе работы.
Есть идея использовать запароленную базу данных SQLite. Это защитит данные от модификации, но остается возможность подмены самого файла БД на его более раннюю версию (например заранее скопированную после установки ПО). Как вариант можно вести версионность файла БД и в реестре прописывать ключ с последней версией файла БД. Но и это не панацея, можно при работе программы отследить изменения в реестре, и затем откатить файл БД и значение ключа. Нужен совет, как защитить данные? Какие есть практики?

Comment: Если это корпорация - комп в домене, можно проверять время. Так же время можно проверить через интернет.

Comment: Покуда данные хранятся там, куда у пользователя есть доступ, он их всегда может подменить. Разница только в том, насколько ему для этого придётся заморочиться.

Comment: Не обязательно препятствовать подмене данных, достаточно это обнаружить.

Comment: Можно добавить файл с "подписью" базы, который солится, постоянно обновляется при работе программы, в случае не работы в течении n-дней становится "просроченым" Тогда через n-дней уже не смогут подменить. Можно... n сделать переменным (на выходные празники длиннее).

Comment: Я чего-то не улавливаю, наверное, но если ваша база зашифрована, то какой может быть резон в подмене файла база предыдущей версией? Будут же потеряны тогда введенные данные с начала пользования программой. И зачем нужны записи в виндовом реестре ежели вы имеете базу, пишите все что нужно туда. Программа поставляется с нулевой базой и требует регистр.ключ. Вы продаете юзеру ключ, ключ затем шифруется и записывается в базу. Программа стартует и проверяет наличие ключа в базе, если такого ключа в базе нет значит...

Comment: Хранить базу на сервере?

Comment: В базе хранятся счетчики определенных событий, пользователь заинтересован чтобы значения счетчиков были как можно меньше или БД была пустая.

Comment: Так, понятно, в чём заинтересован пользователь: _чтобы БД была пустая_. А в чём заинтересованы _вы_?

Comment: В идеале защитить данные от модификации и удаления, приемлемым вариантов является обнаружение подмены/редактирования.

Comment: Ну добавьте ещё одно поле в которое помещайте контрольную сумму всех или выборочных полей по определённому алгоритму. А потом будете знать менялась ли запись или нет.

Comment: Если юзеру будет сильно надо, он поставит виртуалку, установит на неё вашу прогу, сделает снепшот и будет откатываться на него пока не надоест. Потому, если вы не планируете привлекать какой то сервис/сервер для защиты, то проблему, по крайней мере я, затрудняюсь решить